# Netbeans java files as a project

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I downloaded the source files (contained in folders) for javadoc and doclet (some folders like com/sun/tools/doclets/... with some .java source files in them) and I would like to load it into Netbeans as a project (all the .java files that are somewhere starting in the com directory), so that I am able to work with it easily.

Are there any ways, how to make it (there is quite lots of them, so I do not want to start new project and add them manually one by one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing I can think of is to add a pom.xml to javadoc project, then open/import the project into netbeans.

I am going to make some assumptions here as I don't know the exact directory layout.

Assuming the code is checked out into javadoc/src/com/sun/...

- create a new file called **pom.xml** in the **javadoc** directory.
- The pom would look something like the following -> http://pastebin.com/i5hshAF3

Comment: How should the pom.xml file look like and where should I place it? Thanks :)

Comment: Seems I found it :). Thanks:)

Comment: It seems working, just a point to your last edit. When you have this line in your pom.xml: <groupId>com.sun.javadoc</groupId> then I would assume directory tree as com/sun/javadoc (which it actually really is) :)

Comment: No, the groupId, artifactId and version are used to resolve dependencies. In the pom.xml there is a <dependencies> tag from which you can import other projects EG: spring. In this instance, they are not needed per se(Not sure if you intended to distribute this) but maven will fail as the pom.xml is malformed without them.

Answer (score 0):

just create a project and find out  where it is saved and then just add all the .java files and it will load in the netbeans